# Select top Values For each day of Specified month

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am sorry if the question is silly because i'm new to SQL Server. I want to select top 5 records for each day of specified month.
e.g.

```
top 5 records for day 1 in month september
top 5 records for day 2 in month september
top 5 records for day 3 in month september
.
.
top 5 records for day 31 in month september
```

and show these all records as a one result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you're checking speeding records for the month June 2012, and you wanted the top 5 speeds (by speed `desc`).

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT *, RowNum = Row_number() over (partition by Cast(EventTime as Date)
                                          order by Speed desc)
      FROM Events
     WHERE EventTime >= '20120601'
       AND EventTime <  '20120701'
  ) X
 WHERE RowNum <= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
WITH TopFiveRecords
AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dayColumn ORDER BY colName DESC) RN
    FROM tableName
)
SELECT  *
FROM TopFiveRecords
WHERE RN <= 5 
      -- AND date condition here ....
```

`dayColumn` the column that contains the date of the month 
`colName` the column to be sorted